# Unable to add a column which contains a Button to a dynamic DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am working on an application to creating dynamic datagrids based on the tables in returned dataset.
All tables may have different columns so i creating dynamic datagrid on basis of row count and set AutoGenerateColumns = true;
Here is my C# code:

```
 for (int count = 0; count < ds.Tables.Count; count++)
            {
                DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
                dg.Name = ds.Tables[count].TableName.ToString();
                dg.Margin = new Thickness(5);
                dg.Width = 800;
                dg.MaxHeight = 200;
                dg.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
                dg.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
                dg.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
                dg.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[count].DefaultView;
                stkCollection.Children.Add(dg);
            }
```

I want to add an extra column with every dynamic datagrid which have a button in every row.

Here is my XAML:

```
<GroupBox Header="Log Details">

    <Border  >
        <Grid Background="{StaticResource NormalBackground}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" MaxHeight="600"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Button Name="btnMessage" Content="Message" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Width="120" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="right" Click="btnMessage_Click"></Button>
            <Button Name="btnDraw" Content="Draw" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" Width="120" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="right" Click="btnDraw_Click"></Button>
            <StackPanel x:Name="stkCollection"  Grid.Row="3"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="8" Orientation="Vertical"/>


        </Grid>

    </Border>

</GroupBox>
```

Any one have any idea.
How i do this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `DataGridTemplateColumn` as a resource in Xaml like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Key="DGTemplateColumn">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="Info" Click="DGCell_Button_Click"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</Window.Resources>
```

Add this to your DataGrid in code:

```
DataGrid.Columns.Add(FindResource("DGTemplateColumn") as DataGridTemplateColumn);
```

And handle the click event of the button (here i display the name of an employee using the Buttons's DataContext which is the underlying object that is being displayed in that row):

```
private void DGCell_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Employee emp = (sender as Button).DataContext as Employee;
    MessageBox.Show(emp.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for quick reply..
I found the solution...
Here is my code...

```
for (int count = 0; count < ds.Tables.Count; count++)
            {
                DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
                dg.Name = ds.Tables[count].TableName.ToString();
                dg.Margin = new Thickness(5);
                dg.Width = 800;
                dg.MaxHeight = 200;
                DataGridTemplateColumn dgc = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
                DataTemplate dtm = new DataTemplate();

                FrameworkElementFactory btnReset = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Button));
                btnReset.SetValue(Button.ContentProperty, "Restore");
                btnReset.SetValue(Button.ToolTipProperty, "Restore Selected Row");
                btnReset.SetValue(Button.DataContextProperty, new Binding("TableName"));

                btnReset.AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(btn_Click));

                //set the visual tree of the data template  
                dtm.VisualTree = btnReset; 
                dgc.CellTemplate = dtm;
                dg.Columns.Add(dgc);
                dg.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
                dg.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
                dg.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
                dg.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[count].DefaultView;
                stkCollection.Children.Add(dg);
            }
```

Thanks..

Comment: @user649985: this is not an answer. You can update your original question with edits or comment on your own question or others' answers.